# rails new sample_app stuck on bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, terminal, osx-snow-leopard

I've just installed *Ruby, Rails, Git and RVM* on my Macbook running Snow Leopard 10.6.8 All is good, except when I run rails new sample_app, it gets stuck at run **bundle install**

Is there any way to speed this up/ It's like this for about 10 minutes, and I wonder if I did anything wrong..

This is the command used to install *RVM, Ruby and Rails*:

```
$ \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails --autolibs=enable
```

Do I need to do anything else? It's painfully slow...

```
 rails new demo_app
  create  
  create  README.rdoc
  create  Rakefile
  create  config.ru
  create  .gitignore
  create  Gemfile
  create  app
  create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
  create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
  create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
  create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
  create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
  create  app/assets/images/.keep
  create  app/mailers/.keep
  create  app/models/.keep
  create  app/controllers/concerns/.keep
  create  app/models/concerns/.keep
  create  bin
  create  bin/bundle
  create  bin/rails
  create  bin/rake
  create  config
  create  config/routes.rb
  create  config/application.rb
  create  config/environment.rb
  create  config/environments
  create  config/environments/development.rb
  create  config/environments/production.rb
  create  config/environments/test.rb
  create  config/initializers
  create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
  create  config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb
  create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
  create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
  create  config/initializers/secret_token.rb
  create  config/initializers/session_store.rb
  create  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
  create  config/locales
  create  config/locales/en.yml
  create  config/boot.rb
  create  config/database.yml
  create  db
  create  db/seeds.rb
  create  lib
  create  lib/tasks
  create  lib/tasks/.keep
  create  lib/assets
  create  lib/assets/.keep
  create  log
  create  log/.keep
  create  public
  create  public/404.html
  create  public/422.html
  create  public/500.html
  create  public/favicon.ico
  create  public/robots.txt
  create  test/fixtures
  create  test/fixtures/.keep
  create  test/controllers
  create  test/controllers/.keep
  create  test/mailers
  create  test/mailers/.keep
  create  test/models
  create  test/models/.keep
  create  test/helpers
  create  test/helpers/.keep
  create  test/integration
  create  test/integration/.keep
  create  test/test_helper.rb
  create  tmp/cache
  create  tmp/cache/assets
  create  vendor/assets/javascripts
  create  vendor/assets/javascripts/.keep
  create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
  create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.keep
     run  bundle install
```

Comment: Is the log outputting anything? It can take a while the first time to download and bundle everything.

Comment: So it will do this only the first time, or do this for each "new" command? The log just gets stuck there. And i've used ctrl+c after 10 minutes or so... I was watching a tutorial, did everything like in it, and in the tutorial the "rails new app" was almost instant..

Comment: Probably something else then if the output is stuck. I suggest updating your question with the logs.

Comment: As long as you have a good connection, it should only be stuck on bundle install for a minute or two.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are behind a proxy, and this is why the Bundle it's not working as faster as you want.

Set HTTP_PROXY environment var pointing to your proxy url.

Answer (score 0):

you can manually install all these gems

```
bundle install
```